# Cordova. I use push notification or scheduller?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, schedule

I want to develop an app that works with Cordova as follows. 
On the server side will be a database of messages and these messages should be delivered to certain devices that correspond to the owners posts. The question is this, do a service on the side of the phone that is checking from time to time if there are any messages for him or do I have the server send these messages by push, I do not know exactly the right way since it never made a similar application . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sending the messages through push from the is the best way.**

**Drawbacks for client side checking:-**
If you write a code on client side(in phone) to check for messages time to time, you need to handle events like when the app is not in use, managing the scheduler when internet connection is not available etc.

**Advantage of push from server:-**
Incase of push you will receive notification even when app is not in use, the user will know about the new messages received for him and all notification sent by you will automatically be received whenever the user is online.

I have used this practice for several apps and I had received good feedback on usabiltiy